# How to discover the users of an action?

Tags: animation, actions, data-blocks

This blend file contains a Sphere, a Cube and a Cone.

[image]

The action CubeAction acts on the cube. In the Action Editor, it can be seen to have 2 users. So it must also act on another object, but which one, the sphere or the cone?

In this case I can just just select the sphere & cone in turn to see which one causes the Action Editor to focus on CubeAction. But what if there were many objects?

Actions don't seem to appear as a node in the outliner that I could expand to somehow see what objects they are getting applied to.

Blender 2.83.3 on Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type the name of the Action in the Outliner "Live Search" field :

[image]

In this example, "CubeAction" is attached to both Cube and Cone objects.